# GUI SFTP client that will copy files and folders locally instead of downloading/uploading

Tags: shell, sftp, copy, graphical-user-interface

I'm looking for a GUI client (preferably Windows) that will recognize when you copy files remotely, and will default to running a local shell command (f.a :

```
sfpt> !rsync -a /files/ /copyoffiles/
```

in SFTP)

Does something like this exist already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're lots of web file managers, one of them may do the job. I recommend [eXtplorer](http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/): nice, fast & handy :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no such feature in SFTP itself. I believe you'd better learn how to manage files over SSH :) Repeated actions work well with cron, all the rest can be done manually or with the help of some simple bash scripts

Comment: It's not for me, but for the designer, who has to be able to copy large projects locally. I tried getting him to log in using ssh and run the shell commands himself, but he does not want to...

The feature does exist : Just try prepending the shell (bash/sh/whatever is set for the user) command you want to run remotely with an exclamation mark (!) in the sftp shell.

Comment: Maybe some web file-manager would do the job for him better? I've not heard of any SFTP clients capable of that. Dolphin - KDE's file manager - also fails to copy files locally on the remote host: there should be reasons for that :) For instance, `rsync` may be missing or '!'-commands are disabled as a security risk.

Comment: Recommend me a web file-manager for php/apache/linux rhel5 in another answer and I'll accept that answer! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

http://winscp.net/ may be worth investigating for your designer.